# BiBtex line break

Tags: bibtex

I edited an BibteX file and it works so far that it shows all information I need.

```
FUNCTION {electronic}
{ output.bibitem
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  url output
  format.date "year" output.check
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

with

```
@Electronic{L2PwikiAAS,
  title     = {Wiki des L2P-Lernraumes},
  year      = {05.12.2016},
  url       = {https://~/collaboration/Lists/WikiList1/Atomabsorptionsspektroskopie%20(AAS).aspx},
}
```

but the URL is very long and it goes over the end of the page.

What should I do to get a linebreak somewhere in this URL?

And how can I add the string 'Zuletzt aufgerufen am:' before the date?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url

Comment: Can't you simply add year      = {Zuletzt aufgerufen am: 05.12.2016}, it might not be elegant but it works (i guess)

Comment: This is for use just in 'normal'. I try do line break a url in an included bibtex reference.

Comment: Something like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected ?

Comment: That was a good hint to change my code. I just put \url{...} around my link and included the url-package which auto wraps it for me.

Comment: Sweet, so maybe it is best to delete the question ? Or you can add an answer your self.

Answer (score 1):

You can add characters, after which a line break is allowed: https://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/how-to-break-long-urls-in-bibtex/

Just add e.g.: `\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}` right after `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}`